# Does uniformly bounded second moment imply Lindeberg's condition>

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose an independent sequence $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is such that $\sup_n E(\Vert X_i \Vert^2) \leq M$ for some constant $M$. Does this imply that $X_n$ satisfies the following Lindeberg-type condition:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE\left( \Vert X_i \Vert^2 I\{\Vert X_n \Vert \geq \epsilon \sqrt{n}\} \right) \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}

It seems clear to me that the sum does not diverge, since it is bounded by $M$, but is it true that it goes to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No.

Try $X_n= n.\mathcal{Bernoulli}(1/n^2)$

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to get this to hold with some minimal addition conditions on $X_n$?

Comment: You see if I'm not mistaken, any condition that makes $(X_i^2)$ uniformly integrable is sufficient. For example $sup\mathbb{E}( |X_i|^{2+\epsilon})< +\infty$, however,that seems a bit tautology as the  Lindeberg-type condition is a way for us to get around the uniform integrability.